# JQuery Datatable width increases when I add data using $("#table").DataTable().row.add()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am dynamically adding data into the table which is made with the jquery DataTable library. I initialize the table with the following code.

```
$('#table').DataTable({

            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            bPaginate:false,
            buttons:
                [{
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    postfixButtons: ['colvisRestore'],
                    collectionLayout: 'fixed two-column'
                }],

            responsive: true,
        })
        .draw(false);
```

I added the data using the following code

```
$("#table").DataTable().row.add(["column1","column2","column3"]).draw(false);
```

The problem is that when data has entered the width of the table is also increased due to the long value of the cell. I am using a responsive plugin which works fine when data is inserted before loading the page.
The one solution that I could find was adding the following code after adding the data

```
$("#table").DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
```

But as I am not using ajax request in my initialization this code shows an error with the following alert
[Screenshot from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIoma.png) 
[chrome console error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsM7Y.png)
Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: You should embed screenshots here on SO. External resources could eventually disappear someday.

Comment: Please provide code snippet to demonstrate the problem. .